# Restructuring data in excel

Tags: excel, vlookup, reorganize

I am trying to condense data in a specific way. I want any occurrences of the number 1 in each column to show up as 1 (regardless of how many times it occurs) with the corresponding site, in the corresponding column. Some sites occur multiple times in the original data, and I want to make it so that only one of each unique site shows up in the resulting data table with a 1 for the corresponding column if there any 1's in the column from the original data.

I would think it would be a vlookup function, but I have tried many different things and I am really stuck on this.

Image of original data and what I am trying to do:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Is 1 and blank the only options for the cell content?  If that's is the case, you could use pivot table with `MAX` function instead of `SUM`.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that your data set only contains 1 or blank and this approach uses a Pivot Table with `MAX` function.  Below are details in case anyone doesn't know Pivot Tables.

Select a cell in your data and insert Pivot Table.  Note, I added a title for column A, as you need that in the Pivot Table.

[image: Original Data]

Click in the created Pivot Table and the PivotTable Fields dialog should pop up.  If not, right click in Pivot Table and select Show Field List.

Drag the Field names (Code, a, b,& c) down to the appropriate blocks below.  (Values under Columns will be created for you.)

[image: Pivot Table]

Click on the drop down arrow next to each field name and select Max.  That will rename it to "Max of ...".  If that bothers you, then you can type the name you want into the Custom Name field.  Note, it will not let you type the same name as the field name, eg `a`, but it will work if you put a space in front of it.

[image: Pivot Table Settings]

Comment: You can also change the `Row Header` names from `Max of b` to just `B` by typing over. If you get an error message saying the field already exists, just type in `B` with a lagging space ("B ")

Comment: I should have added that I am working with a very large data set, where there are a lot of columns. Is there a faster way to do this than a pivot table? It would take a lot of time for me to change the settings for each column. Thanks

Comment: I've posted an alternate method that may be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the Pivot Table would be a lot of work for a large number of columns, here is a formula based approach.  Put this formula in cell `G2`, then drag it down and across to fill your new table.

Note, you will have to populate all codes that you have in column F. And if any new codes are added later you will have to keep this updated.  One of the advantages of a Pivot Table is that it will do this for you.

I know that you won't be putting this in these cells, so adjust accordingly.  In fact, I would recommend this be in another sheet.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A:$A,$F2,B:B,1)>0,1,0)
```

[image: Formula solution using COUNTIFS]

`COUNTIFS($A:$A,$F2,B:B,1)`

This will count each occurrence when the value in column A matches your code `$F2` AND the value in column B equals 1.

If that count is `>0`, then you know that at least one match was found and the `IF` will return `1`, otherwise `0`.